# gcnew KeyEventHandler compile problem (VC++)

Tags: event-handling, managed-c++, visual-c++

My managed c++ code fails to compile with the error message

```
.\Window.cpp(11) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::Windows::Forms::Form ^' to 'Enviroment::Window ^'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
.\Window.cpp(11) : error C3754: delegate constructor: member function 'Enviroment::Window::_keydown' cannot be called on an instance of type 'System::Windows::Forms::Form ^'

Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::Windows::Forms::Form ^' to 'Enviroment::Window ^'    c:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project_X\Project_X\Window.cpp    11
Error   2   error C3754: delegate constructor: member function 'Enviroment::Window::_keydown' cannot be called on an instance of type 'System::Windows::Forms::Form ^'  c:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project_X\Project_X\Window.cpp    11
```

In window.h

```
ref class Window
    {
    public:
        Window();
        void _keydown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^ e);
    }
```

In window.cpp

```
Window::Window()
    {
        Form^ form = gcnew Form();
        form->KeyDown+= gcnew KeyEventHandler(form, &Window::_keydown);
}
```

and later

```
void Window::_keydown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^ e)
    {
        //stuff
    }
```

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to say:

```
form->KeyDown+= gcnew KeyEventHandler(this, &Window::_keydown);
```

In C++, a class function pointer is comprised of 2 things, the actual pointer (this part you got right) and a pointer to "this" to be passed to the function, which is of the type of the class holding the function. This is your `Window`, not Microsoft's `Form`.